# How do you create an APFS volume inside an ordinary file?

Tags: apfs

Normally in the Disk Utility you need to select a device.  Is it possible to create an AFPS volume as an ordinary file in other filesystem?  And if so, how would that be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Disk Utility application or a combination of the `hdiutil` and `diskutil` commands. The files can be either full images (`.dmg`) or sparse images (`.sparseimage`). You can also create a sparse bundle which is actually a folder (`.sparsebundle`) containing files. The sparse bundle can be used, for example, to create a 10 GB APFS drive on a physical partition that is FAT32 formatted. This would allow a person save a file greater than 4 GB on a drive/partition that was physically FAT32 formatted.

Below is an example of where the Disk Utility is used to create a 1 TB FAT32 formatted sparse image.

1. Open the Disk Utility application.
2. From the menu bar select `File->New Image->Blank Image...`.
3. Enter the following information, then click on `Save`.
   [image]

An example of creating a 10 GB APFS sparse bundle is given below.

> Note: This sparse bundle folder is created in the FAT32 sparse image from the previous example.

1. Open the Disk Utility application.
2. From the menu bar select `File->New Image->Blank Image...`.
3. Enter the following information, then click on `Save`.
   [image]
4. If the Disk Utility hangs after the pop up shown below appears, then Force Quit the Disk Utility.
   [image]

Answer (score 6):

If you have a file that contains a raw image of a disk, you can use the following command in the Terminal:

```
hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage myimage.raw
```

If you haven't got an existing image, you can create a new, empty file named `myimage.raw` and then attach it without mounting:

```
hdiutil attach -imagekey diskimage-class=CRawDiskImage -nomount myimage.raw
```

Then you can create APFS volumes on there as you would have a physical disk and mount them. This can be done via the command line with a command such as:

```
diskutil apfs create disk5 MyNewVolumeName
```

where `disk5` needs to be replaced with the device name, you've received from the attach command earlier.

Comment: When creating a new, empty image, the third command above results in: Started APFS operation on disk6
Creating a new empty APFS Container
Unmounting Volumes
Switching disk6 to APFS
Creating APFS Container
newfs_apfs: wipefs: Invalid argument
Error: -69626: Unable to create a new APFS Container